# Partial template specialization depending on a variadic pack of integral constants of mixed type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Suppose one needs to partially specialize a template type that expects a variadic list of types for the case where all of its arguments are specializations of, say, `std::integral_constant`.

The following straightforward approach is accepted by various versions of clang and GCC, but rejected by VS 14 (2015) with the error:

> error C3522: 't': parameter pack cannot be expanded in this context

```
template<typename...>
struct foo;

template<typename... t, t... v>
struct foo<std::integral_constant<t, v>...>
{
    /* ... */
};

foo<std::integral_constant<int, -1>, std::true_type> bar;
```

I can't seem to find anything in the C++ standard drafts (n4296) that definitively either allows or disallows such types of pattern matching, so before I file a bug report against VS 14, I should better consult the gurus out there:

**Is the above example really valid C++?**

Comment: ... and if it's not valid, what is a suitable alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ill-formed. [temp.param]/p15:

> A template parameter pack that is a pack expansion shall not expand a
>   parameter pack declared in the same *template-parameter-list*.

`v` is both a pack and a pack expansion, and it expands `t`, which is declared in the same *template-parameter-list*.

Comment: oh well, I guess I should file a bug report against GCC and clang instead

Comment: bug reported for [clang](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24625) and for [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67397)